# Convert External refernce to real formula in excel

Tags: vba, excel-formula

My cell is having external refernce to another excel file..to retrieve value I need to press F2 and Enter each time..can I automate this with excel VBA.Can anyone help me to solve this

Comment: Can you give an example of such an external reference?

Comment: a photo? It does not show the complete formula. Please post the complete formula. You can take a screenshot. Or copy and  paste the formula. You don't need to use a camera to photograph your monitor!!

Comment: 'C:\Users\Desktop\DUMP files\[DAY1.xlsx]SALES'!$F$15

Comment: Please show the whole formula. The context matters.